# How to setup a grub dualboot with Kubuntu 18.04 and windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, kubuntu

Hello everyone and thanks for reading this

I have Windows 10 and Kubuntu 18.04 installed on different SSDs and I would like to set up a clean dual boot with Grub.

At the moment I use the 'choose boot device' of my motherboard by pressing F8 during boot.

I have tried to use boot-repair but it absolutely doenst change anything. In the log it seems that Windows 10 is detected though.

Boot-repair report : http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QPgQHNWCVk/

Do you have any idea ? Thanks !

[EDIT]

I have tried again with boot repair and it messed my install completely. 
Here is my [boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/543Jq.jpg) now.

The first one (windows) is working, so the MBR of the windows disk is fine.

But the second (Windows) and the last (ubuntu) are not working and lead to this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNUEg.jpg). They are both on the same disk where kubuntu ubuntu should be installed.. it is not normal I guess...

Can you please help ? I am totally lost at this point !

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Boot-Repair added a Windows entry. But grub has not. You can run `sudo update-grub` But if Windows is hibernated it will not find it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  It looks like you had sdc set as default boot but put Windows on sda? And what is sdd. Did you let Windows convert to dynamic? Is that then your Windows, not sda2? Your sdd should just be standard gpt partitioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried to read the wikipedia articles you gave me. Windows is not hibernated as I disabled the hibernation on windows.

Comment: I have tried again with boot repair and it messed my install completely. 
Here is my [boot menu](https://i.imgur.com/zUgPErv.jpg) now.

The first one (windows) is working. But the second (ubuntu) and the last (ubuntu) are not working and lead to this [error](https://i.imgur.com/JuRlrFq.jpg).

Can you please help ? I am totally lost at this point